# Handle Nullpointerexception after SQL query has no result

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I've got a MVC based Java application with three models: `Room`, `Student` and `StudentRoom`.

`StudentRoom` contains an object of `Room` and `Student`.

Now I've got the problem that if my SQL query returns no result and I check the value of student's name like this

```
if(studentRoom.student.name != null) {
}
```

I'll get a `NullPointerException` and I don't know how to handle it.

Should I set `Student.name = "";` since my query has no result?

Comment: If the SQL query has no result you shouldn't be trying to get a student name in the first place.

Comment: You should try to prevent NPE from happening, e.g. initializing the data structures used to store the result to empty collections, instead of null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(studentRoom != null && studentRoom.student != null && studentRoom.student.name != null){
  //.. Access student
}
```

Above solution looks a bit weird. you should better use `getter/setter` methods instead of directly accessing the objects.

Apart from that you can define methods like `isStudentAvailable()` in `studentRoom` to check whether it has `Student` in it or not.

> Should I set Student.name = ""; since my query has no result ?

It completely depends on your use case. But I must say better to keep it `null` as it will raise the exception instead of passing the `null` check validations.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a try/catch statement for that. Something like this :

```
try {
    // do process here
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    //to do if student is null
}
```

But take note, if there are any object that is inside the try statement, a `NullPointerException` would still be thrown. Hope this helps.

Comment: A NullPointerException is usually a sign of a programming error and should not be catched. Instead, you should try to fix the root cause causing the NPE